# Merging together multiple shapefiles with block level data for each state into a single country wide shapefile

Tags: python, pandas, shapefile, geopandas

I am trying to use python to merge together multiple shapefiles into a single shapefile. I have one shapefile for each American State that contains the geographic boundaries of the State and some internal block level boundaries within the State. I want to put all of these shapefiles together into one shapefile for the entire country. Does anyone know how I could do this in python. I have looked at geopandas but their joins seem to be for overlapping data not just appending new data.

Comment: Try put your code first and then if you still confused or got some error then asked in SO [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask]

Answer (score 0):

Geopandas data frames have a method dissolve() which aggregates geometric shapes. In the example below, the provinces of Zambia are aggregated into a single shape for the whole country. More information about .dissolve is available [here](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html).

```
# Zambia provinces
zambia_provinces.head()

ADM0_EN     ADM0_PCODE  ADM1_EN     ADM1_PCODE  geometry
0   Zambia  ZM  Central     ZM10    POLYGON ((29.99949 -12.00267, 30.00002 -12.002...
1   Zambia  ZM  Copperbelt  ZM20    POLYGON ((27.94644 -12.28198, 27.95514 -12.297...
2   Zambia  ZM  Eastern     ZM30    POLYGON ((33.25764 -11.58238, 33.26164 -11.585...
3   Zambia  ZM  Luapula     ZM40    POLYGON ((29.37374 -8.70908, 29.36164 -8.72298...
4   Zambia  ZM   Lusaka     ZM50    POLYGON ((29.98254 -14.64278, 29.98494 -14.643...

zambia_provinces.plot(edgecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# Aggregate the provinces and show the changes
zambia = zambia_provinces.dissolve(by='ADM0_PCODE')
zambia.head()

    geometry    ADM0_EN     ADM1_EN     ADM1_PCODE
ADM0_PCODE              
ZM  POLYGON ((28.83832 -16.43402, 28.83588 -16.439...   Zambia  Central     ZM10

zambia.plot(edgecolor='black')
plt.show()
```

[image]